# Reenable disabled Elementor widget via child theme

Tags: child-theme

We hired an agency to develop a wordpress theme including some new Elementor widgets. Unfortunately they disabled some of the stock Elementor widgets in their Core theme

```
add_action('elementor/widgets/widgets_registered', function($widgets_manager){

    $widgets_manager->unregister_widget_type('icon');
    $widgets_manager->unregister_widget_type('icon-box');
    //etc

}, 15);
```

Is there an option how to reenable Elementor widget via child theme funcions.php? I dont want to mess with the core theme files at all.

Comment: Yes. The option is to contact them. Obviously, when you've bought the theme, you've bought it's support.

Comment: Yes, that's seem appropriate, but not the correct one answer :D

Comment: What is correct answer? A piece of code covering your needs? Get out.

Comment: @jam if the code in question is how they disabled the widgets, then you could try registering the widgets back using the same hook. Basically, copy that code, paste into your functions file, change the 15 to 16, and call the method for registering the widget, e.g. `$widgets_manager->register_widget_type( 'icon' )`, but of course I don't know whether that method exists and could simply be called like that.. You could try, but if it doesn't work, then you should contact the agency (or ask on the Elementor's support forums) for further assistance.